# Format PHP date string

Tags: php, date, format

I want to convert a date string to a specific date format
I'm currently using `strtotime` to convert a date, but it doesn't get the correct hour

My code

```
<?php
        $timestamp = 'Fri, 10 Aug 2018 11:00:00 GMT ';

    $formatted = strtotime($timestamp);

    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $formatted);
?>
```

It gives me 01:00 pm instead of 11:00
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Let me guess, you're in a UTC+2 timezone currently?

Comment: i thought it could be the problem, i'm on utc-3 actually. Any solution?

Comment: Could you try `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s P', $formatted);` to see what timezone your computer thinks it's in?

Comment: I can't figure out the source's (from the string) timezone, but mine's says +02:00

Comment: So although you are in UTC-3, your computer thinks it's in UTC+2? Seems like a misconfiguration, and I'd strongly suggest to solve the problem there instead of overriding the timezone. It will be a lot easier to maintain that way.

Comment: No, it's +02:00 actually, see i'm getting this datetime string from an api, what i want is to record in a database, but mysql only supports yyyy:mm:dd h:m:s format, so i want to convert, but if i convert it as it is it's going to record 01:00 pm, is there any solution i can use?

Comment: So, `$timestamp` is like what you're getting from the API (including the GMT string?), in that case you can do as @BojanSrbinoski suggest, and select time zone `UTC` there. However, as you're definitely not in UTC, by doing this you skew the timestamps by whatever your offset from UTC is.

Comment: By doing this i should guess the correct UTC right? Yes it comes with GMT string on the end :(
I still don't get how can i get the correct date conversion so i can record it

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); to header.

Comment: *"but mysql only supports yyyy:mm:dd h:m:s format"* - About what you said; MySQL supports other formats also, such as a UNIX timestamp for instance. Here @jcortes have a look https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html and more precisely https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp as well as UTC.

Comment: @jcortes You should have probably have mentioned that a  (mysql) database was part of the picture here, unless you think it's not important.

Answer (score 0):

**php.ini**

```
date.timezone=UTC
```

or

**.php file**

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time())."\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time())."\n";
```

or

**.htaccess file**

```
php_value date.timezone UTC
```

--

If the timezone you are using is not UTC, check the following urls:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/TWS/SC32-1274-02/en_US/HTML/SRF_mst273.htm